# How to render "Transaction Forms PDF Layouts" in NetSuite

Tags: pdf, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am able to render Advanced PDF template/Email Template but not Transaction Forms PDF Layouts. 
I tried below:

`var renderer = render.create();
renderer.setTemplateById(104);
var fileObj = renderer.renderAsPdf();`

But I get Missing_PDF_Parameter error.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Glancing through the docs, it looks like you are missing the actual transaction record that you want to render, as well as the PDF template code.  I tested with using their XML from the docs and it worked for me.  Try something like the below.

```
require(['N/render','N/record'],function(render,record){
  function testing(){
    var xmlStr="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
               "<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC \"-//big.faceless.org//report\" \"report-1.1.dtd\">\n" +
               "<pdf lang=\"ru-RU\" xml:lang=\"ru-RU\">\n" + "<head>\n" +
               "<link name=\"russianfont\" type=\"font\" subtype=\"opentype\" " +
               "src=\"NetSuiteFonts/verdana.ttf\" " + "src-bold=\"NetSuiteFonts/verdanab.ttf\" " +
               "src-italic=\"NetSuiteFonts/verdanai.ttf\" " + "src-bolditalic=\"NetSuiteFonts/verdanabi.ttf\" " +
               "bytes=\"2\"/>\n" + "</head>\n" +
               "<body font-family=\"russianfont\" font-size=\"18\">\n??????? ?????</body>\n" + "</pdf>";
    var renderer=render.create();
    renderer.templateContent=xmlStr;
    renderer.addRecord('record',record.load({
      type:record.Type.INVOICE,
      id:123456789
    }));
    var invoicePdf=renderer.renderAsPdf();
  }

  testing();
});
```

Link to render docs: 
[2.0 render.TemplateRenderer](https://debugger.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4412042824.html#bridgehead_4412220541)

Comment: Even if the transaction is empty it should print the layout. Data can be secondary. I don't error when rendering Templates/Advanced PDF.

Error is only when i try Custom PDF Templates

Comment: Correct.  That's what I found, as well (I mentioned the missing invoice record, since that should be there before trying to create a PDF).  If the template is not correct (the docs don't really show anything specific about what is needed in there) it returns that error.  I tested this with one of my PDF templates, and it worked fine, so I'm guessing there is something missing from your PDF template..?

Comment: Data I can add once I get the Template in XML/String format. Let me know if you get any details.

Comment: Did you try using that sample template?  It seems that the issue is with your template code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample working snippet which prints the Invoice PDF and saves a copy in the File Cabinet. For invoices, the Subsidiary record has to be added if your PDF Template includes subsidiary values in it.

```
var idInvoice = ''; //Invoice ID
var sInvNum = ''; //File Name
var idFolder = ''; //File Cabinet Folder
var nPDFTemplateId = 1; //Integer value of the PDF Template Internal ID

var recInv = record.load({type: 'invoice', id: idInvoice});
var idSubsidiary = recInv.getValue({fieldId: 'subsidiary'}); //Subsidiary ID
var recSubsidiary = record.load({type: 'subsidiary', id: idSubsidiary});
var rendererInv = render.create();
rendererInv.addRecord('subsidiary', recSubsidiary);
rendererInv.addRecord('record', recInv);
rendererInv.setTemplateById(nPDFTemplateId);
            
var pdfFileInv = rendererInv.renderAsPdf();
pdfFileInv.folder = idFolder;
pdfFileInv.isOnline = true;
pdfFileInv.name = sInvNum;
idFileInv = pdfFileInv.save();
```